# Best way for users to navigate between different people on a page?

Tags: navigation

Im creating a page where only one persons details can be displayed at any one time.

However, the user needs to be able to navigate between different people easily from this page. If the list was small, I would display a carousel type widget so users can see how many people are on the list & which person is currently highlighted.

But the list could be big (20 - 40 people). Best way i can think to do this would be to display the person as a dropdown and allow the user to navigate to different people this way.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like Telerik does with their [PanelBar](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/panelbar.aspx):

[image]

*Click the link above or the image to view the different demos.*

Answer (score 0):

Vertical tabs would be the right solution.

Considering the list could run longer than 30 names, you can provide a search feature on the top.

This approach stands good even on a mobile device, with the list moved into a sidetray.

[image]